# I don’t understand how to use the alpha factor in RGB Node in the Shader Editor

Tags: node-editor, transparency

I don’t understand how to use the alpha factor in RGB Node in the Shader Editor.

So far, I’ve investigated and get some of the uses for the alpha factor when it comes for project images on planes or for brushes, but I don’t understand how is it supposed to work when it comes to nodes.

My problem is that, from what I understand from the concept, when alpha value is up to 0, the RGB color isn’t supposed to be visible, yet, it is in the material preview and the rendered image (No matter the value, I don’t see changes on the transparency of the color).

Comment: Color sockets have an alpha in Geo Nodes and the Compositor, but AFAIK not in Shader nodes. You can set an alpha on RGB nodes or Color sockets, but it is completely ignored for Shaders. I don't know why they don't hide the Alpha for Shader nodes...

Comment: Thanks! i couldn’t figure it out

Comment: The alpha factor has absolutely no effect on the transparency of a color in almost all settings. Not in the _RGB_ node,  not in color ramps or any color fields where you can set a color. Not in the _Texture Properties_ tab either. It can only be used in the _Compositor_ and _Geometry Nodes_.